# Is there a way to find the line of code a query is running on in a SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a long running query session, I'd like to find out what line (piece of code in a sproc) it's currently running in SQL Server?

In an active user session, there's no query plan available that I can look into for a user process who ran "select into" or "Insert" inside a sproc.  I tried to look into the  sys.dm_exec_requests to see if there's such a linenum column for that active session but there isn't.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suggest you try [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive).

Comment: Note: Query are execute as a batch. Not line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.dm_exec_requests` only returns the `sql_handle`, you need to pass that to `dm_exec_sql_text` to get the text. Then you can use some calculation to work out the text of the running statement

```sql
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(st.text, (r.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1,   
        ((CASE r.statement_end_offset
          WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)  
          ELSE r.statement_end_offset  
          END - r.statement_start_offset) / 2) + 1) AS statement_text  
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
WHERE r.session_id = @someSPID;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Charlieface. It truely helps what I'm looking for.